# Pandas cumsum with initial value

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

So given the following single column data frame:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame({0: {'10/10/2012': 50, '10/11/2012': -10, '10/12/2012': 100})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
              0   
10/10/2012   50   
10/11/2012  -10  
10/12/2012  100
```

I would like to create a cumulative sum for a given column, but give the accumulator an initial value. So for the dataframe above and with an initial value of 100, this would look like:

```
              0  1 
10/10/2012   50  150 
10/11/2012  -10  140
10/12/2012  100  240
```

Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: can't you just add 100 to your result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame({0: {'10/10/2012': 50, '10/11/2012': -10, '10/12/2012': 100}})

print(df)
```

That will give you the following result

```
              0
10/10/2012   50
10/11/2012  -10
10/12/2012  100

df[1] = df[0].cumsum()+100

print(df)
```

After creating a new column `df[1]`, take the cumulative sum of `df[0]` then add 100 to it.

```
              0    1
10/10/2012   50  150
10/11/2012  -10  140
10/12/2012  100  240
```