# Cumsum with Percentage Column with an Initial Value

Tags: pandas

I have the following Dataframe.
I want to start with initial value, let's say 100. I want to plot the cumsum result, 105, 102.9, 103.2087.

```
timestamp   percentage
XXX         5
YYY        -2
ZZZ         3
・
・
・
```

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921862/pandas-cumsum-with-initial-value) and tried `df['percentage']/100*100` but not working.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Well convert your numbers into proportional offsets (`df = df.eval('coef = (percentage / 100) + 1')`):

```
coef
1.05
0.98
1.03
```

Then just do `df['coef'].cumprod()`.